# TS - lost type information on filtered keys in curried function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function that takes an object and set of keys that construct new type by picking by those keys.

I works fine when both parameters are defined in same function, but not when I try to make this function into function that takes only object parameter and returns function that takes in the keys.

I prepared test function that illustrate the issue:

```
const test = {
  first: '',
  second: '',
  third: '',
};

export function fromObjectWithKeys<T extends { [key: string]: unknown }, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, ...keys: K[]) {
  return (a: K) => a;
}

const res = fromObjectWithKeys(test, 'first', 'third')
//here type of res is: (a: ("first" | "third")) => ("first" | "third")
```

This one works as expected with second key not being present, next example however fails, losing information about filtered keys:

```
export function fromObject<T extends { [key: string]: unknown }, K extends keyof T>(obj: T) {
  return (...keys: K[]) => {
    return (a: K) => a;
  };
}

const withKeys = fromObject(test);
const resFromKeys = withKeys('first', 'third');
// here resFromKeys type is: (a: ("first" | "third" | "second")) => ("first" | "third" | "second")
```

In second example information was lost when part of function was manually curried.
How was type information lost?
How can I fix it so I am able to have second function accept only one parameter while preserving types down in the hierarchy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the function that's returned generic, moving `K` from the outer function to that function:

```typescript
export function fromObject<T extends { [key: string]: unknown }>(obj: T) {
  return <K extends keyof T>(...keys: K[]) => {
    return (a: K) => a;
  };
}
```

Then you get the same result as previously:

```
const withKeys = fromObject(test);
const resFromKeys = withKeys('first', 'third');
// here resFromKeys type is: (a: ("first" | "third")) => ("first" | "third")
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0YF4YG8BQMYDMCWATtAFwwDkZANFjBPKGACakXXZQAWhz5VGAvgG4MGeAA8ADiAKwcAVzDAoecLgIgAtgHkARgCt6UADwAVGOIRMI6GAG0A1vACepaATxgA5gF1SC+2AgAO5gMPwAfAAUIPqkJgCU6DQE8FByBKFGANLmYpaM1o5OIDgwJlEAdFVFEKRZtt6JyOFJ2NgpaRkwkQCGdU0tPcLYQgIiDEhBeJxZztaoOOra+oaRCNDxwhOwKRAAYkuzTvMwUzNzkWT4RFBU5JzcZJsYAPQvbdgAegD8r+8c8BSMF2B00R2sUCcEngMDwtW6fW6ACJrtAkTAAD4wJEPAiMJHxAbI1FQdFYnFcPEEoA)

(Thank you [spender](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14357/spender) for pointing out that we could *move* `K` rather than using a new generic!)

Comment: Could be further simplified by dropping the second generic parameter from the outer function: See [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEWKhAWwHkAjAK2AwB4AVOUGYFAEwGc4BvOAbQGtgAngC44rGFEwoA5gF0RqXiggB3XAF8AfAAoI5ETQCUnAFBw4UYDCRRcVANL0QjFu34CICODW0A6P29YRO24ZIwBeDRMzMwsrGzgtAEMg8MjEgG5TODVMtWNjNBwxOEZisKjETCgxEQByWoAaLNZKHGY6xqyYAAsq9rh6ppz8wpRi5Uweu0F2coR8YnJKGC1SmANM0eKLVgAxBemBWbgJqZmtWoQqsUaBnr7ajaA)